# How to pass multi-valued characters in SSRS Report?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have a SSRS report that has 3 data sets feeding off one data source. The main dataset is a stored procedure that is aggregating some data based on a set of parameters powered by the other two datasets.

The main stored procedure powering this report has 4 parameters. One is an ID for the type of data, two are for start and end dates and the third is just a flag parameter. The flag parameter is the multi-valued parameter where I want to pass multiple flag values that are also VARCHAR values.

In my stored procedure for my @Flag parameter, I have the common:

```
WHERE [Flag] IN (@Flag)
```

Then of course the @Flag parameter on the SSRS report set to allow 'Multiple Values' that are also populated from a query that is pulling those @Flag values from a dimension table.

**My Problem**

In most cases when dealing with INT values, using the same technique works. However, when I'm dealing with character values, it fails. If I choose one flag, the report works magically. If I select more than one flag, it doesn't seem to pass the flags correctly to the stored procedure and no results return.

When testing the multi-value flag directly in the stored procedure:

```
WHERE [Flag] IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

The stored procedure works correctly. So the problem is not the stored procedure, but how SSRS is passing the multi-valued values to the @Flag parameter.

**Solutions Tried**

I tried doing the following adjustments to the SSRS dataset for this @Flag parameters:

```
=join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")
```

AND this one too:

```
=SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,","),",")
```

These all work on single values, but never multi-values.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution. I did not properly split the values in the stored procedure with a UDF.

To pass multi-values correctly in this stored procedure, I would need to add the following code to the dataset parameter that I am using:

```
=join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")
```

This is basically going to join multiple values into an array and pass it through the `@Flag` parameter. The next step is adding SQL to the stored procedure to receive and digest the values correctly so it reads the values with the `IN` clause.

Google search any UDF string parser online. There are many to choose from. I used `dba_parseString_udf` from Michelle Ufford http://sqlfool.com.

Once I had my UDF installed, I can now alter my `IN` clause to receive the new multi-valued parameter being passed by SSRS as follows:

```
WHERE [Flag] IN (SELECT * FROM dba_parseString_udf(@Flag, ','))
```

Therefore, SSRS will pass the following value:

```
@Flag = 'A,B,C'
```

Then my UDF will parse that string out correctly to:

```
A
B
C
```

And populate my `@Flag` parameter correctly with `SELECT * FROM UDF()...`

Comment: In case this helps anyone else:  the join expression (`=join(Parameters!<your param name>.Value,",")`) can be added to the dataset ***reading*** the parameter, under the "Parameters" tab:  there is an "fx" button for adding expressions, to the right of the "Parameter Value" drop-down.

Comment: Also, instead of creating a UDF to parse, ***if the database value and parameter values are reliably unique*** and never subsets of each other, then I skip parsing and just use CHARINDEX:  for example, if the code to read the parameter in embedded SQL was:  `WHERE <Table>.[<Column>] IN (@MultiValueParm)`, then the code in the stored procedure could be `WHERE CHARINDEX(<Table>.[<Column>], @MultiValueParmAsText) > 0`

Comment: Great Q&A, thanks! FYI, http://SQLFool.com appears to be down. The ParseString() function can be found at: https://github.com/MichelleUfford/sql-scripts/blob/master/dev/dba_parseString_udf.sql